# XML File in use by another process

Tags: c#, xml, file, process

Recently, I began developing an application that utilizes the use of XML documents in a C# program. Everything worked fine to begin with, but as I edited the code, and added a bit more features to the program in case the XML gets deleted, corrupted, etc, the program didn't want to function properly anymore.

The following code is used when submitting the data and transferring it to XML:

```
    private void doneCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Initialize new XMLDocument class.
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        //See if the card data file is there, if not, create it.
        if (File.Exists(xmlPath) == false)
        {
            using (FileStream createFile = File.Create(xmlPath))
            {
                Byte[] FileData = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(toBase64("<studycards></studycards>"));
                // Add some information to the file.
                createFile.Write(FileData, 0, FileData.Length);
                createFile.Close();
            }

            XMLData = "<studycards></studycards>";
        }
        else
        {
            XMLData = readXML();

            if (XMLData == "")
            {
                XMLData = "<studycards></studycards>";
            }
            else
            {
                XMLData = fromBase64(XMLData);
            }
        }

        XmlDoc.LoadXml(XMLData);

        XmlElement Group = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Group", null);
        XmlAttribute Group_Attr = XmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
        Group_Attr.Value = groupName.Text;

        Group.Attributes.Append(Group_Attr);

        foreach (string[] Card in CardData)
        {
            try
            {
                FrontData = Card[0].ToString();
                BackData = Card[1].ToString();

                NewCard = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Card");
                FrontElement = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Front");
                FrontElement.InnerText = FrontData;

                BackElement = XmlDoc.CreateElement("Back");
                BackElement.InnerText = BackData;

                NewCard.AppendChild(FrontElement);
                NewCard.AppendChild(BackElement);
                Group.AppendChild(NewCard);
            }

            catch
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        XmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Group);

        XmlTextWriter write = new XmlTextWriter(xmlPath, null);
        write.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        XmlDoc.Save(write); 
    }
```

Upon attempting to click "Done" in the application, I'm presented with the following Exception:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Toshiba\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\StudyCards\StudyCards\bin\Debug\Resources\card_data.xml' because it is being used by another process.

Any solutions?

Comment: Make sure you flush, close, dispose where appropriate and use the using statement around objects that implement IDisposable.

Comment: One suggestion is to get rid of that try/catch block. Ignoring exceptions is never a good thing. Also, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may well be at least *part* of the problem:

```
XmlTextWriter write = new XmlTextWriter(xmlPath, null);
write.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
XmlDoc.Save(write);
```

You're never closing the writer, so I would expect it to keep the file open. That will stop future attempts to open the file, until the finalizer kicks in.

Alternatively it could be part of `readXML()`, which you haven't shown - again, if that leaves the file open, that would cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Actually, the following is from readXML();

        private string readXML()
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xmlPath))
            {
                string XML = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                return XML;
            }
        }

So it does close. I'll see the XMLDoc and see if the problem somehow gets fixed like that.

Will get back to you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have fixed the problem, referring to the "write". Of course, this'll help. Apologies for not including it in the top post: This is where the error is coming from: XmlTextWriter write = new XmlTextWriter(xmlPath, null);

Comment: @JacobApixen: Did you have the file open in any other process? Is this repeatable? Can you create a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: After reading the reply you gave me and making a "short but complete program" to demonstrate the problem, I've found that the problem could be located in the "if(File.Exists(xmlPath) == false" clause. Investigating at the moment.